# How to upload multiple file by multiple users in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

I'm trying a scenario where I have to upload 50 files by every 10 users simultaneously.

To do so, I have configured 2 CSV files 1 for "files" which will be input for my HTTP request, another CSV file for "users" which will be input for my HTTP header.

When I run this, all 10 users upload the files, but it takes files randomly and all 50 files are not uploaded.
(from user1 30 files uploaded, user2 5 files, and so on)

How can I improve my script in which all 10 users upload all 50 files?

Here is my testplan structure

[image]

No.of Threads : 5,
Ramp-up :1,
Loop count: 1

loop controller, loop count: 50

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What is your "Sharing Mode" setting for the second CSV Data Set Config? Default is `All threads`

[image]

which means that each thread (virtual user) reads the next value from the CSV file on each hit/iteration. You can double check the variable value using [Debug Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) and [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener combination.

If you want each user to upload all the files from the folder - consider switching the "Sharing Mode" to `Current thread`, this way each virtual user will be accessing the CSV file "individually"

More information: [CSV Data Set Config in Sharing Mode - Made Easy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/csv-data-set-config-in-sharing-mode-made-easy)

Also you may find [Directory Listing Config](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/directory-listing/DirectoryListing.md) plugin easier to use